# SSRS Converting parameters to int

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

As topic says SSRS Report is converting varchar Parameters to int. the parameter is a text type and when i enter 0002 in the report designer pop up for the stored procedure the report doesnt work but in reviewing sql profiler we can see it's converted to int.

Need help.

Comment: Are you saying you want the SP to see "0002" not 2 as an int?

Comment: What data type do you have selected for your parameter? What data type is the stored procedure expecting?

Comment: shellNija that's correct. the datatype I have for param is Text and stored proc is varchar(100) but I've tried 1000 & 4000

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you want to remove leading 0's from the string, and then convert it to int (for example convert '0002' to 2), you can use this to pass the parameter from your report and execute the procedure:

```
 CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@parameter, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', @parameter), LEN(@parameter)))
```

Replace `@parameter` with your parameter name from the report.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about passing a parameter to your stored procedure from RDL. 
go to Report Parameter Properties (on left Report data pan in BIDS when you open report RDL) 
select parameter and right click and go to properties. 
select data type as Text. this should work for you.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Dataset Properties:

[Dataset Properties Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs38x.png)

Go to the Parameters section. Click on the "fx" button to create an expression for the Parameter Value. Use the CInt function to convert your parameter to an int:

[Dataset Properties - Set Parameter Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTzrP.png)